# SDL delete GL Context memory safety

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

If I get an OpenGL context via SDL with

```
SDL_GLContext* SetupOpenGL(SDL_Window *wnd) {
    SDL_GLContext *context;

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);

    assert(wnd != 0);
    *context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(wnd);

    return context;
}
```

is it enough to free that `SDL_GLContext` with `SDL_GL_Deletecontext` on exit, or do I need to do something else?

Comment: Actually if your program is about to terminate, then cleaning up behind yourself is mostly a gesture. In fact most modern OS system developers now openly criticize programs that do this kind of on-exit cleanup. Worst case scenario: The program did allocate gigabytes of stuff which got swapped out of system RAM and lay dormant. If the program just terminated the entries in the memory allocation table would just be marked "free" and that's it. But if the program cleans up, all this stuff has to be loaded into the RAM again… for what, just to be killed immediately.

Comment: Correctly deallocating objects is important if your program is *not* about to terminate, but does it in the process of allocating new objects. Then you want to clean up, as not to waste memory and address space through leaking memory.